# mssql database class with php - getting error on next results

Tags: php, sql-server, class, oop, methods

I am trying learn more about OOP by building a mssql class with php.

I am running into this error "Warning: mssql_next_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in"...

I understand what the problem is... my executeQuery() method returns the value of "true"
and is causing the error.

But the method is setting the variable $result by using $this->result = $result; inside the class. This in my mind is where the query results I want live. But I am not sure how to get it.

Is there a better way to build this method to test the connection and return the value of what I need or should I be connecting to the variable directly in another way.

Thanks for the help.

but I am not sure how to call it correctly/ properly to get the  while (mssql_next_result($rs));  to work because $rs is a bool and it needs to be an array.

The funny thing is... even though its a bool the do while is still building the table so my code is working it just not doing it without an error.

So again I know that the error is I just don't know how to fix it.

### MY CODE

```
<?php

// create new instance of mssql Class
$Users = new SQLServer();
// use connect() method
$Users->connect();


// get user list
$rs = array();
$rs = $Users->executeQuery('Select * FROM Users');



    if (!$Users->numRows($rs)){

        echo 'No records found';

    } else {

    do {

            while ($row = $Users->fetchArray($rs)){

                    echo 'DO STUFF';

            }
        }

        while (mssql_next_result($rs)); 
    }


    $Users->freeResult();
    $Users->disconnect();
 ?>
```

### MY CLASS

```
<?php 
    class SQLServer { 
        //connection parameters
        private $db; 
        private $host; 
        private $user; 
        private $password; 

        //handle the connection 
        private $conn; 

        //query results
        public $result; 
        public $numReg; 

        /** 
        * Constructor 
        * @param $db database name
        * @param $host name do host database
        * @param $user  database user name
        $ @param $password database password
        */

        static function SQLServer() { 
            $varDb          = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
            $varHost        = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
            $varuser        = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
            $varpassword    = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
            $this->db       = $varDb; 
            $this->host     = $varHost; 
            $this->user     = $varuser; 
            $this->password = $varpassword;  
        } 

        /** 
        * Connect to mssql and returns true if it automatically selects the base 
        */

        function connect() { 
            $this->conn = mssql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password) or die("Database Connection Error"."<br>". mssql_get_last_message()); 
            if ($this->conn) { 
                mssql_select_db($this->db, $this->conn); 
            }     
        } 

        /** 
        * Return a query 
        * @param $str string valid mssql 
        * @return true query execture com Ãxito, false error na query 
        */

        function executeQuery($str) { 
            $result = mssql_query("$str") or die("Error executing Query"."<br>".mssql_get_last_message()); 
            if ($result) { 
                $this->result = $result; 
                $this->numReg = mssql_num_rows($this->result); 
                return  true; 
            } 
        } 


        /** 
        * Return index line of query results
        * @result index a line of query results 
        */

        function fetchRow() { 
            return mssql_fetch_row($this->result); 
        } 

        /** 
        * Returns the contents of one cell from a MSSQL result set.
        * @result indexed rows from a executed query
        * @Param $line an indexed line of executed query
        * @Param $field string t index row from a  executed query
        */

        function result($line, $field) { 
            return mssql_result($this->result, $line, $field); 
        } 

        /** 
        * Returns a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both
        * @result array of indexes of names and a row of query results
        */

        function fetchArray() { 
            return mssql_fetch_array($this->result, MSSQL_BOTH ); 
        } 

         /** 
        * Proceeds to next record.
        * Not working
        */

        function nextResult() { 
             return mssql_next_results($this->result); 
        }

        /** 
        * Returns  the number of records affected by the query
        * @result number of rows affected
        */

        public function affectedRows() { 
            return mssql_rows_affected($this->result); 
        } 

        /** 
        * Return Gets the number of rows in result arary
        * @result number of lines
        */

        public function numRows() { 
            return mssql_num_rows($this->result); 
        } 

        /** 
        * Clears the pointer results 
        * @result clean results pointer 
        */

        public function freeResult() { 
            return mssql_free_result($this->result); 
        } 

        /** 
        * Disconnect from the database
        * @result disconnect database 
        */

        public function disconnect() { 
             return mssql_close($this->conn); 
        }


    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the error. You are trying to loop through `true`. It's not `$rs` where the data is. You put it in  `$this->result`. You are doing that wrong because `$result = true` you are putting a boolean in the `$result` variable.

Currently your `$result` variable can only hold 1 value. I suspect you want to add multiple rows so change it to an array: `$this->results = array();`.

Then Change the `executeQuery` function to add the rows of the query to the `$results` variable":

```
function executeQuery($str) { 
    $result = mssql_query("$str") or die("Error executing Query"."<br>".mssql_get_last_message()); 
    if ($result) { 

        while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $this->results[] = $row;
        }

        $this->numReg = mssql_num_rows($this->result); 
        return  true; 
    } 
}
```

Now you have stored the rows in your `$results` variable. Because it's a public variable you can access it with `$users->results`. So if you want to loop throught the data you can use something like this:

```
foreach($Users->results as $row){

    echo $row['A_COLUMN_NAME_OF_THE_TABLE_USERS'];

}
```

Note that i do recommand a private/protected variable with getters and setters instead of a public variable.

If you want to do the row loop and get the row field in the class itself you can do something like this:

```
class SQLServer { 
    //connection parameters
    private $db; 
    private $host; 
    private $user; 
    private $password; 

    //handle the connection 
    private $conn; 

    private $currentRow = -1; 

    //query results
    public $result; 
    public $numReg; 
    public $results = array(); 


    /** 
    * Constructor 
    * @param $db database name
    * @param $host name do host database
    * @param $user  database user name
    $ @param $password database password
    */

    static function SQLServer() { 
        $varDb          = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
        $varHost        = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
        $varuser        = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
        $varpassword    = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
        $this->db       = $varDb; 
        $this->host     = $varHost; 
        $this->user     = $varuser; 
        $this->password = $varpassword;  
    } 

    /** 
    * Connect to mssql and returns true if it automatically selects the base 
    */

    function connect() { 
        $this->conn = mssql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password) or die("Database Connection Error"."<br>". mssql_get_last_message()); 
        if ($this->conn) { 
            mssql_select_db($this->db, $this->conn); 
        }     
    } 

    /** 
    * Return a query 
    * @param $str string valid mssql 
    * @return true query execture com Ãxito, false error na query 
    */
    function executeQuery($str) { 
        $result = mssql_query("$str") or die("Error executing Query"."<br>".mssql_get_last_message()); 
        if ($result) { 

            while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $this->results[] = $row;
            }           

            $this->result = $result; 
            $this->numReg = mssql_num_rows($this->result); 
            return  true; 
        } 

        return false;
    }       

    //Get a field of the current row
    function getField($field) { 
        return $this->results[$this->currentRow][$field]; 
    }       

    //Checks if there is a next row
    function nextRow() {
         $this->currentRow++;
         return $this->currentRow <= ($this->numReg - 1); 
    }

}
```

You can use that with e.g. :

```
$Users = new SQLServer();
$Users->connect();

$rs = $Users->executeQuery('Select * FROM Users');

if($rs)
{
    while ($Users->nextRow()){

        echo $Users->getField('USER_FIELD_1');
        echo $Users->getField('USER_FIELD_2');

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I will read through and make adjustments. I appreciate your response.